# How to efficiently use nested modules in Typescript

Tags: typescript, import, module, export

Consider the following source typescript file "src.ts":

```
export module moduleA {
    export enum enumA {
        val1 = 0,
        val2 = 1
    };
};

export module moduleB {
    export module moduleC {
        export enum enumC {
            val3 = 0,
            val4 = 1
        };
    };
};
```

And consider the following file as consumer in the same folder:

```
import { moduleA, moduleB } from "./src";

const A: moduleA.enumA = moduleA.enumA.val1;

const B: moduleB.moduleC.enumC = moduleB.moduleC.enumC.val3;
```

This works just fine, even if a little verbose.  But now to try to address the "verbose"-ness of this situation and make the code easier to read, I want to do something like:

```
import { moduleB.moduleC.enumC as enumC } from "./src";

const C: enumC = enumC.val3;
```

But this is a compiler error -- "Module has no exported member moduleC".

Except actually it does!

In my case I would sometimes like to go even a couple of levels deeper into nested modules, and if I am willing to write them out in all their dereferencing glory with every use, no problem.  But I can't figure out how to dereference into the nest in the import statement.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Hah, first you made nested modules, and then you argue that it is verbose : ) Why in the world you want nested modules then?

Comment: To precisely reflect domain types in a complex cascading set of namespaces on the server that get serialized into JSON objects for AJAX calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

Use the `import` keyword differently to [*move a type*](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/moving-types):

```
import { moduleA, moduleB } from "./src";    
import enumC = moduleB.moduleC.enumC;
```

Comment: Some further notes: This link no longer works; another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165362/2854555) says this behaviour is deprecated. So probably should be avoided?

Comment: Link updated. Appreciate the comment 