# Typescript: Import from nested modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I am running a **react application**. The code below does not work because of the following error message:

> `import =` is not supported by @babel/plugin-transform-typescript
> Please consider using `import <moduleName> from '<moduleName>';` alongside Typescript's --allowSyntheticDefaultImports option.

apiTypes.d.ts

```js
declare module ModuleA {
    declare module ModuleB {
        export interface ModuleABInterface {
        }
    }
}
```

token.ts

```js
import ModuleABInterface = ModuleA.ModuleB.ModuleABInterface
let test: ModuleABInterface
```

What would be the correct solution to import from nested modules?

Comment: Simplest solution: don't use nested modules?

Comment: So it is not possible to nest modules? Your answer is not helpful at all..

Comment: Btw it looks like you just want a type alias, not an import. Use `type ModuleABInterface = ModuleA.ModuleB.ModuleABInterface;
let test: ModuleABInterface` for that.

Comment: You can use it, it’s just babel cannot parse it. Problem is in your build tool, not source code. Use the official typescript compiler would solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to nest ES6 modules. [TypeScript namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) (that were originally called "modules") can be nested, [but should be avoided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export-as-close-to-top-level-as-possible). And yes, it's impossible to import *from* them - you can only import the namespace object itself, using normal ES6 `import` declarations (not the deprecated `import =` syntax), then access their properties.